# iPhone: Completely different project for Lite version of my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've run into a bit of a dilemma.

I'm considering making a lite version of my app that will be for free but will run on iAds. The Lite version will therefore have different .xib files because I have to make room for those iAds.

So what's better, should I just make some more .xib files in my project and then somehow programmatically load them. Or should I just create a completely new project (copy & paste 
my old directory) and create the lite version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely don't fork it. You will regret it big time down the road as you'll have to merge virtually every commit across projects. (And XIB files can't be merged...)

I don't even know if you necessarily need to create additional XIB files. You could probably just conditionally resize/hide the necessary views in code. But even if you have to create additional XIB files, it doesn't compare to the pain you'll go through from forking.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a different target within the same project.  You can include different combinations of xib and source files within each target, and use some #ifdef's in your source code to limit features or functionality in the Lite version of the target by using a preprocessor define in the Lite target Build settings.