# iPhone app free and paid

Tags: iphone

I have almost finished my iPhone app and would like to send it in for approval. However, I would like to make this available as a free app, as well as a paid app. In the free version, advertisements will show up, and in the paid version, advertisements will not show up.

My question is, to create a free app and a paid app, do I need to create two similar projects in Xcode, and for one, add the code for advertisements to appear?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: Completely different project for Lite version of my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171051/iphone-completely-different-project-for-lite-version-of-my-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way will be to copy the target, get a second appID, probably with a "Free" or a "Pro" tacked on the end, then try to make one a very finely different, IE. including a header that defines a single value `kFreeVersion`, or something. then use that to define your logic.
so you don't end up having to maintain 2 branches.

Comment: "Lite" is usual convention :P

Comment: I resent the word 'lite', as far as I can tell was invented by a beer company... did I say resent... I mean like.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an in-app purchase to buy the full version and remove the ads. This way users won't have to download your app again.

See the [in-app purchase programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more info.

Comment: But it can be a pain for users to do this for multiple devices..

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You need to have two seperate versions, one with space for ads, and one without. In many cases, the paid version will have extra features, in addition to the lack of ads. In your case, it doesn't sound like you have extra features, so the two versions should be very similar.

Comment: or, add an in-app purchase option to remove the ads, leaving only the free version in the store

Comment: But that would take away the ability to get the paid version first, if one was to desire it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to create two separate products. If you spend a little time looking around in the app store, you'll notice that many apps have free and paid versions; sometimes the free versions have the word "Free" in their title; sometimes the paid versions have "Pro" or something like that.